# Odd "inheritance" of linkage between variables

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that would perform an iterative operation on each member of a list `input` and then remove that member. Although this doesn't make sense for the minimalist code I've pasted below, I wanted the function to conclude by checking the product of its operation against the original `input` list - therefore, the very first step of the function creates a list `originals = input` that is intended to preserve this starting list, for checking at the end.

Here's the minimalist version of my function:

```
def process(input):
    originals = tuple(input)
    members = []

    print('Step 0\nOriginals: {}\nList: {}\nMembers: {}'.format(originals,input,members))

    step = 0

    while len(input)>0:
        step += 1
        members.append(input[0])
        input.remove(input[0])
        print('\nStep {}\nOriginals: {}\nList: {}\nMembers: {}'.format(step,originals,input,members))
```

As can be seen, I create `originals` in the beginning, and then don't touch it throughout the rest. Yet when I call `process(['a','b','c'])`, the output is:

```
Step 0
Originals: ['a', 'b', 'c']
List: ['a', 'b', 'c']
Members: []

Step 1
Originals: ['b', 'c']
List: ['b', 'c']
Members: ['a']

Step 2
Originals: ['c']
List: ['c']
Members: ['a', 'b']

Step 3
Originals: []
List: []
Members: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

As intended, the function sequentially moves each element of `input` to the new list `member`, but at the same time deletes them from `originals`. Presumably this reflects some linkage established between the lists, when I made the initial `originals = input` assignment.

If I use `originals = tuple(input)`, everything works as expected. So I can proceed with my work, but I'm not satisfied. Why does `originals` experience the operations that I perform on `input`, and is there a better way of doing this than copying it to a tuple?

Apologies in advance for newbism, I made an effort to try and answer this via Google but I'm not sure I'm even asking the question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are mutable.  When you create a new reference to a list, you're not making a new list.  Making a tuple of the list does what you want because tuples are immutable, you're not making a new reference.  Alternatives are to use the copy() method of the list, or a slice [:]

```
k = [1, 2, 3]
k2 = k  # reference to k
k3 = k.copy()  # a copy of k
k4 = k[:]  # also a copy of k
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense - I'd forgotten about how Python uses references, perhaps because it was counter-intuitive to me. Is there a scenario in which one would really want to have two named lists referring to the same contents? I.e. what was the purpose of having `k2=k` ever mean anything other than `k2=k.copy()`?

Comment: @C.Murtaugh Glad it helped, I sometimes still get bitten by this (if it answered your question, please consider accepting it as the answer).  As far as the default referencing (or 'aliasing') behavior goes, like anything in programming there will be a number of possible uses, but I'll give you an example of how I use it.  When running a simulation, I will use a `k_new` and `k_old` to track time steps.  Then at the end of an iteration, I can do `k_new, k_old = k_old, k_new` and the two lists swap places without ever creating a new list.  Saves time and memory over creating a new pair of lists.

Comment: @C.Murtaugh You bet.  I think a lot of us who come from other languages have some difficulty with mutable types.